# WCF RESTful Service - How to debug?

Tags: wcf, rest

I am starting out on a WCF project that has an underlying RESTful architecture to it.  I have so far a Service Class and a Service Contract via an Interface in place.  If I go to my Solution Explorer and right-click on the .svc file (Service Class) and View in Browser, I can view my Data Sources in a RESTful way, e.g. Addresses/ and /Employees/.  But here's my problem, there are some Classes that can't be displayed, i.e. I get the "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" message.  My question is, how can I debug through my code so I can find out where the problem is, i.e. so I won't be using 'View in Browser'.  I don't want to create a complex Client (UI)... I would just like my Service to be accessible via the HTTP so when I type in say Service.svc/Employees, the Employees collection loads.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) to interactively test your REST services.

Answer (score 1):

How complex does the client have to be in order to test your service?

Consider that you will be asking other developers to use your service. If *you* can't even create a client to use it, then how do you expect *them* to be able to use it?